# Is $\frac {e^{\frac 1x} + 1} {e^{\frac 1x}}$ the derivative of some function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

I need to determine if there exists a differentiable function $f$ in $\mathbb R$ such that for every $x \neq 0$ , $f'(x)=\frac {e^{\frac 1x} + 1} {e^{\frac 1x}}$

I've been pondering this for quite a while, but I really have absolutely no idea how to approach this question. I would really like to hear how one tackles this, what the thought process is, and about different methods/approaches/theorems.

**EDIT:**

For clarification, this question is part of Calculus I. Although I know about integrals to some extent (from high-school), they haven't been discussed in the course. So this needs to be solved without them. And, according to some comments, I believe what I am after is a closed form "primitive", elementary function.

Comment: Yes, because the known function is continuous on intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Begin by simplifying your expression into $1+e^{-1/x}$. It is doubtful that this function has a **known** primitive function.

Comment: @aschepler That says there is a differentiable function on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty$ with the right derivative. The question asks about a differentiable function on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Aha, good point. There are functions such that for $x \neq 0$, $f'(x)$ exists and equals the given function. But the function cannot be differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Note
$$
g(x) = \frac{e^{1/x}+1}{e^{1/x}} = 1+e^{-1/x}
$$
From this we see
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = 1,\qquad \lim_{x \to 0^-}g(x) = +\infty ,
$$
so $g$ is discontinuous at $0$.  But aside from $0$, the function is continuous.  So we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.
$$
f_1(x) = \int_1^x g(x)\;dx
$$
exists for all $x>0$ and $f_1'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x>0$.
And
$$
f_2(x) = \int_{-1}^x g(x)\;dx
$$
exists for all $x<0$ and $f_2'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x<0$.

---

A "closed form" integral can be written in terms of the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

$$
f(x) = x(1+e^{-1/x}) - \operatorname{Ei}_1(1/x)+C, \quad x>0,
\\
f(x) = x(1+e^{-1/x}) + \operatorname{Ei}(-1/x)+C, \quad x<0.
$$
These are not [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

---

There is no function differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$ so that $f'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \ne 0$.  If $f$ is differentable on on $\mathbb R$ then $f'$ has the [intermediate value property](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Mathematical_Analysis_(Zakon)/04%3A_Function_Limits_and_Continuity/4.09%3A_The_Intermediate_Value_Property).  But $g$ does not have the IVP, even if extended by to have some value $g(0)$.  Indeed, for $x_1>0$ near $0$, we have $g(x_1)<2$, and for $x_2<0$ near $0$ we have $g(x_2)>3$, so some numbers between $f'(x_1)$ and $f'(x_2)$ are not values of $f'$.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know I had to further clarify my question, mainly due to lack of knowledge from my side. Please refer to my edit.

Comment: no. the question asks about a function differentiable on $\Bbb R$. That includes the origin...

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. Check Darboux Theorem: the derivative of a function always has the intermediate value property (IVP).

Since $\;f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0^-]{}\infty\;$ and $\;f'(x)<2\;\;\forall x>0\;$ , and $\;f'(x)\neq 2\;$ for any real $\;x\;$ , this function doesn't fulfill the IVP

Comment: I believe this is the desired approach. Can you please elaborate a bit more and explain more thoroughly?

Comment: I think almost all is already said/hinted there. You only need to check that the two facts I wrote about $\;f'\;$ are indeed true and then apply Darboux Theorem. If you still need some specific clarifications on something please do write back.

Comment: Isn't the hole in domain problematic in applying Darboux Theorem?

Comment: @Esgeriath That hole in domain would be, if at all, a problem of $\;f\;$ , not $\;f'\;$ . But even if not, a discontinuity point $\;x_0\;$ of the derivative of a function has to be an essential one **but not** such that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)=\pm\infty\;$$ and this alone would also give the same result as above: the given function isn't the derivative of a function.

Comment: @Esgeriath There is no hole in the domain. We're given that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Exactly so, David. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio In our course we learnt that the derivative of a function can only have essential discontinuity points. The point in the given function is essential. So this cannot disprove the statement.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am still struggling in fully understanding it and putting it into formal writing. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @MCFromScratch I know that, yet the essential discontinuity is so because the limit doesn't exist. It can't be that one of the one-sided limits is $\;\pm\infty\;$ . I wrote that above, and you can check in the web.

Answer (score 1):

People are saying yes, people are saying no. I got it wrong at first. One needs to read the question carefully. Say $$V=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}.$$The answers saying yes show that there is a function defined and differentiable on $V$ with derivative given by that formula. But the problem asks about a function differentiable on $\Bbb R$.

People are saying, correctly it seems to me, that the Darboux theorem shows that there is no such function. Others cite versions of the theorem that are not sufficient (unless they are; the definition of "essential singularity" in a real-variable context is not so clear to me). Yet others don't see why the hypotheses hold...

Let's not cite anything, let's just give a very simple self-contained argument:

> > **Theorem.** Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable. There exist $x_n<0$ with $x_n\to0$ and $f'(x_n)\to f'(0)$.

Proof: Use MVT to find $x_n\in(-1/n,0)$ with $$\frac{f(-1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}=f'(x_n).$$The definition of $f'(0)$ shows that $\frac{f(-1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}\to f'(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the derivative of $f(x)=\int \frac {e^{\frac 1x} + 1} {e^{\frac 1x}} ~dx$ (on a domain that does not include 0).

But I assume you're actually asking if the integral can be expressed in a “closed form” expression with the operators and functions that you learn about in high school.  And the answer to that (at least [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+%28e%5E%281%2Fx%29%2B1%29%2Fe%5E%281%2Fx%29+dx)) is no.  You can only write it in terms of the [exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) function, [or approximate it numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).

Comment: That $f$ isn't exactly a function, since the interval of a definite integral can't include $0$.

Comment: @aschepler Why can't a definite integral have $0$ in its interval of integration?

Comment: @oliverjones: In general, having 0 in the interval of integration is fine.  Just not *for this particular function* which is undefined at $x = 0$.

Comment: @Dan Yeah I understand that, I was just unsure as to why @ aschepler said it in a more general context as they did.